# Can you use query acceleration to query data from parquet file in ADLS using python SDK?

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-lake

This link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-query-acceleration-how-to?tabs=azure-powershell
queries the CSV file to retrieve data from ADLS using python. Is it possible to read parquet file in the same manner (using SQL syntax)?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to read parquet file in the same manner (using SQL syntax)?

Yes, you can read the parquet file for query acceleration to query data from parquet file in ADLS using Python SDK.

Try the following code snippet taken from the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-query-acceleration-how-to?tabs=python#retrieve-data-by-using-a-filter):

Change `blob_format` from `DelimitedTextDialect` to [`ParquetDialect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-file-datalake/azure.storage.filedatalake.datalakefileclient?view=azure-python#:%7E:text=ParquetDialect%22%20(passed%20as%20a%20string%20or%20enum).%20These%20dialects%20can%20be%20passed%20through%20their%20respective%20classes%2C%20the%20QuickQueryDialect%20enum%20or%20as%20a%20string.)

Alternatively, you can provide `ParquetDialect` via `input_format = QuickQueryDialect("ParquetDialect")`

```
def query_hemingway(blob: BlobClient):
    query = "SELECT * FROM BlobStorage WHERE _3 = 'Hemingway, Ernest, 1899-1961'"
    dump_query_csv(blob, query, False)

def dump_query_csv(blob: BlobClient, query: str, headers: bool):
    qa_reader = blob.query_blob(query, blob_format=ParquetDialect(has_header=headers), on_error=report_error, encoding='utf-8')
    # records() returns a generator that will stream results as received. It will not block pending all results.
    csv_reader = csv.reader(qa_reader.records())
    for row in csv_reader:
        print("*".join(row))
```

Reference: [Unable to query blob contents of parquet file](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/22443)

Comment: FYI there is no need to convert parquet to csv just to query it. Completely unnecessary step.